# Can you add a child component while within a JSF Renderer

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee

I would like to add a child component while inside of the encodeBegin

```
 public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context,
   UIComponent component)
   throws IOException {
    XspInputText xip = new XspInputText();

  ViewPickList vplComponent = (ViewPickList) component;
  ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
  String viewName = vplComponent.getViewName();
  if (StringUtil.isNotEmpty(viewName)) {
          xip.setId(vplComponent.getId() + "_InputText");
   xip.setValue("Value");
   vplComponent.getChildren().add(xip);
  super.encodeBegin(context, vplComponent); 


  }
```

This doesn't appear to work, but I am trying to add the child component inside and have it render.  Can anyone suggest a better way of doing this?

Comment: Why do you want to add child components during the rendering phase?

Comment: I"m trying to find a way to make add children components based on the values of the parent component.  It doesn't have to happen at render, just not sure where to put it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call you newly added components `encodeBegin`   and `encodeEnd` methods to render them too.

Try this:

```
  xip.encodeBegin(context);
  xip.encodeEnd(context);
```

Also take a look at [This link](http://cagataycivici.wordpress.com/2005/12/13/dynamically_adding_components_to_a/).

Please give me feed back if it works or not!

Comment: Thanks, I already found a better way of handling this issue, but looking at my code you are right.

Comment: Could you please give a reference or explain your way. Actually I'm doing sth like this now and want to know if there is a better or easier way ;) my use case is a little different, I want to edit existing component not adding new component and i don't know whether doing this in this phase (render response) is right or not?  thanks

Comment: Well, What I found was the way you mentioned was pretty standard for Richfaces and Primefaces, however I am using an IBM implementation of JSF called XPages.  IBM has built in an Interface called FacesComponent that allows if implemented to build children components inside of the component.  The interface is: com.ibm.xsp.component.FacesComponent.